# How to create an array of char pointer in C?

Tags: c

I have to create an array of char pointers each of them of size 10000000 using the best and optimized way to do this in C.

Comment: What do you mean "*each of them of size*...". A pointer doesn't really have a size.

Comment: maybe they want to malloc them in the initialization step?

Comment: like: `char *c[]={malloc(),malloc(),malloc()};` ?

Comment: how many of them in the array?

Comment: @cnicutar Accutally all pointers on an x86 system are 4 bytes in length.

Comment: @Blackninja543: I believe he meant that a pointer's size is not *modifiable* in any way.

Comment: @Blackninja543 The pointer object itself does so, but from the context, i.e. "size 10000000" I'm guessing that's just misleading for the OP.

Comment: @Blackninja543: That's not true. A pointer can be 2, 4 or 8 bytes on x86, depending if it's a 16-bit, 32-bit or 64-bit system. And even then, there's no guarantee as far as C is concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the optimal way because there is only one dynamic allocation, reducing overhead from fragmentation of the heap and the time taken to allocate. You can use the STRING_INDEX utility function to access the nth string.

Also, using calloc() instead of malloc() zeroes out buffer to ensure that all strings are NUL terminated.

```
#define STRING_SIZE 10000000
#define NUM_STRINGS 10

#define STRING_INDEX(array, string_idx) ((array) + (string_idx) * STRING_SIZE)

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *array_of_strings = calloc(NUM_STRINGS, STRING_SIZE);

    // Access 8th character of 7th string
    char c = STRING_INDEX(array_of_strings, 7)[8];

    // Use array

    // Free array when done
    free(array_of_strings);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this will do (haven't checked for nulls though):

```
int i;
int num_arrays;
char **huge_char_array;
num_arrays = 10; //number of arrays you want.
huge_char_array = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * num_arrays);
for(i = 0; i < num_arrays; i++)
{
    huge_char_array[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10000000);
}
```

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc` in C.

Comment: You could use only one malloc outside the loop of num_arrays*10000... and then assign each element in the array apointer with an offset from that allocated memory. but this makes free() a bit stranger

Comment: This is very bad. You're allocating `num_arrays` (10 bytes), instead of `num_arrays * sizeof(char *)` (10 pointers). You'll probably overrun `huge_char_array` after 2 or 3 iterations.

Comment: @netcoder Ohh yes, thanks for pointing that out. It's been more than 6 years when I last touched C (not an excuse, I am just sad).

Comment: @ed-s You are right. Frankly, I had to google it up just to verify:P

Comment: @Abhinav: No shame in that, answering questions on a forum (especially when you don't know the answer right away) is one of the absolute best ways to learn new things.

Comment: @Ed S - I have always cast the return of malloc, why should you not do this?  I'm not exactly an amazing c developer, so I'm curious what I've been missing.

Comment: @Chris: Because in C a `void*` can be implicitly and safely converted to any other pointer type, so the cast is redundant.  On top of that, on older compilers (<= C89) you may forget to include `stdlib.h`, in which case `malloc` will be assumed to be a function which returns `int` and you will get strange problems when you run the code.  The cast hides the error.  Also, these "older" standard compilers are not as rare as you may think.  VS ships with a C89 compiler and they have no plans to meet later standards.

Comment: @Chris: By *stange problems*, it means two things: 1) calling `malloc` without first defining it is actually undefined behavior; and 2) if `malloc` is not defined, and the address it returns does not fit in a signed integer (which is very probable by the way), then you end up with a memory address that is basically an integer overflow, also an undefined behavior. You'll basically end up accessing a totally different memory segment than what `malloc` actually allocated (yes, also totally undefined behavior). Conclusion: there's absolutely *no reason* to.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *arr[SOME_SIZE];
for(int i = 0; i < SOME_SIZE; ++i) {
    arr[i] = malloc(10000000);
    if(!arr[i])
        // allocation failed, do something
}
```

Just realize that you're allocating ~9.5MB for *every element in the array* (i.e., `SOME_SIZE * 10000000` total bytes)

Answer (score 1):

I have been allocating 50K with each request I process this resulted in memory fragmentation. So I switched to allocate 50k * 100 = 5MB and reuse the pool when ever I need to allocate one more. If the requests increases beyond my pool capacity I double the pool size to avoid memory fragmentations. Based on this I would recommend allocating a huge chunk of memory maybe in your case 10 * 10000000 to reuse it. I am sorry but I cannot share the code that handle the pool here. Also use malloc and free and do not use new and delete.

malloc won't through exception it will simply return null if there are no memory available.

if you insist on using malloc for each element individually you can create a heap with maximum size to avoid fragmentations and in that case you will have to define the heap size.

please referee to MSDN for more details about how to create a heap and use it or the other allocation methods available for windows users.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366533(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: *"as you are allocating primitive data type which has no constructor/destructor you should use malloc."* - This question is tagged C, not C++, so what other choice is there? -1 for the C++ lingo that is present in this response.

Comment: forgive me I am new to the StackOverFlow. I will remove that part

Comment: Haha, nothing to forgive :)  It wasn't a personal attack, just have to be careful to discern between C and C++ quesitons.  Once the C++ stuff is removed I'll take my downvote away