# Passing C char array and allocating causing program to crash

Tags: c, windows, memory

I don't know what the error is as this is on Windows and I have no clue how to step through program execution on Windows. Any ideas as to why the program is crashing here (see comment lines)? I think it may have something to do with memory misuse.

```
#define TABLE_MAX_ROW       500
#define TABLE_MAX_COL       20
#define TABLE_MAX_ELT_LEN   60
```

Start here:

```
foo()
{
    char table[TABLE_MAX_ROW][TABLE_MAX_COL][TABLE_MAX_ELT_LEN];

    bar(table);
}
```

Pass to this function:

```
bar(char table[TABLE_MAX_ROW][TABLE_MAX_COL][TABLE_MAX_ELT_LEN])
{
    unsigned int col, row;

    if (table == NULL) { // crashes here
        printf("error: table == NULL!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for (row = 0; row < TABLE_MAX_ROW; row++)
    for (col = 0; col < TABLE_MAX_COL; col++)
        table[row][col][0] = '\0'; // if above if block commented out, crashes here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that's a pretty large array to allocate on the stack.  What happens if you change the "max" values to 1 1 and 1 ?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce any crash in Windows Visual C++ Express.

Comment: Runs fine on my machine, compiled with MinGW, included windows.h and iostream.

Comment: @ddyer Initializing values to `1` `1` `1` makes it not crash. So the large allocation is what's making it crash. Any way around this? (Windows 8) @Razvan yes

Comment: Your code compiled and ran fine on Mac OS X.

Comment: IIRC the standard stack size in Windows is about 1 MB and for Linux it's 8MB, so would say that ddyer is onto something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, the NULL check in `bar` is unnecessary, since `table` isn't dynamically allocated in `foo`.

Having said that, you're *probably* exceeding your stack frame size with that array definition (60 Kb) which causes runtime problems in `bar`, leading to the crash.

Try dynamically allocating the array as follows:

```
void foo (void) // explicitly type all functions
{
  /**
   * Declare a *pointer* to a 2D array of col x len and
   * allocate rows elements of it:
   */
  char (*table)[TABLE_MAX_COL][TABLE_ELT_LEN] =
    malloc(sizeof *table * TABLE_MAX_ROW);

  if (table)
  {
    bar(table);
  }

  free(table);
}

int bar(char (*table)[TABLE_MAX_COL][TABLE_ELT_LEN])
{
  unsigned int row, col;

  /**
   * Some duplication of effort here, since we made the null check
   * in foo, but what the heck.
   */
  if (!table)
  {
    // handle error as above
    return -1;
  }

  // process table as above
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to allocate the space for the 3D array you are creating

char*** table = malloc(sizeof( sizeof( sizeof(char) * TABLE_MAX_ELT_LEN ) * TABLE_MAX_COL ) * TABLE_MAX_ROW)

This will at least give you enough space for all of your elements.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I'm not what you would call fluent with C. Can you please advise how I would incorporate that into the existing workflow? I would prefer not to change the `bar` parameter.

Comment: Well right now your parameter for bar is a char pointer (an array of character [C String]).  As far as I know, you have to change the parameter of the bar function.  You would need to make it a an array of arrays of arrays of character, (array of arrays of string) or a matrix of string.

Answer (score 1):

Program memory is OS-dependent. I strongly suspect that the reason for the crash is your system couldn't satisfy such a large array allocation (almost 0.6MB!) on stack. Better go for `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that there is not enough space on your stack to allocate that large of a buffer. I would suggest you [dynamically allocate](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9b.html) the array.

You could also allocate a flat buffer that you index into using a convenience macro as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908164/how-to-create-an-array-of-char-pointer-in-c/11908363#11908363) post. The only difference is that you're array is "3d" instead of "2d".

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating using 500x20x60=600000 bytes on the stack for your "table" variable.

If your shell is `bash`

`ulimit -s`  (`limit stacksize` for [t]csh)

will display the maximum amount of memory you can use on the stack of programs.
If you use more than this limit, this is the cause of your program segfault.